# Automatic database refactoring to reconcile with refactored python code in OpenERP?

Tags: python, database, refactoring, odoo

When I refactor a Python class (e.g. change the name/type of a field), what is the best way to also reflect these changes in the database?

Currently, I manually run SQL scripts to transfer data to new columns and prune old ones, but this is slow and error prone.

Anything like Liquibase for Java?

Thanks,
Anton

Comment: You might look at the openupgrade server for openerp. They do upgrades between versions, complete with database changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenERP ORM is capable of synchronizing the database schema with the python definition of the models, but it cannot perform complex migration operations. Its purpose is to create or update the database tables and columns necessary to support the newest version of your models, i.e. allow inserting, updating and reading records.

As part of this synchronization, it supports simple schema alterations: as long as the name and type of a column does not change, the ORM will try to update the SQL constraints (NOT NULL, UNIQUE, FOREIGN KEY, etc.), and the ONDELETE rule, if any.

If the type changed, the old column will be renamed to be out of the way (but kept around so you can manually migrate the data), and a new appropriate column will be created. You'll need a manual migration operation if you want to migrate the data [*].

If the only thing that changes is the name of the column, you can give the ORM a hint about that using the `oldname` column property. It tells the ORM that an old column needs to be renamed instead of creating a new one. For example, this column definition would make the ORM attempt to rename `partner_id` to `customer_id` if the `customer_id` column is missing:

```
'customer_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Customer', oldname='partner_id'),
```

You can start the synchronization logic either by launching the server with `` `-u <module> -d <database> `` or by clicking on the "Update" button of the corresponding module in the Settings menu of that database (`--update` is a synonym of `-u`, but make sure to pass `-d` to have it start the synchronization on the database directly).

Note that you should not use the `oldname` parameter when you're in development and just trying out different database schema definitions. This option is mainly useful for keeping track of field renamings between major versions of a given module. For work-in-progress development you don't care about keeping track of all the iterations so using `-u` is sufficient, you should periodically start again on a new empty database anyway.

---

[*] There is limited and mostly undocumented support for embedding your own migration scripts in your modules, where the ORM will automatically execute them depending on the detected module version. Unfortunately the best way to understand how this work is to read [the source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/7.0/view/5156/openerp/modules/migration.py#L56).

Answer (score 0):

Just run openerp-server with -u option:

```
python openerp-server.py -c <your config file> -u <your module>
```

Comment: There is no such option as 'upgrade'.
There is 'update', indeed, but it just updates the module to the latest state, leaving all the deprecated data/columns untouched.

Comment: You can try this while restarting the server: -d <DB Name> -u <Module Name>

Comment: @Pooja, thanks for suggesting.

I've tried it, and found that:
`-u <m.n.>` and `--update <m.n.>` seem to do the same thing, with the only exception that `-u` updates the module immediately on server startup, while `--update` postpones the update until smb connects to the DB with the given module.

Otherwise the server logs are absolutely identical and the effect is the same.

Comment: Under 'the effect' I mean that if I have say `a: fields.char('X-Name')` and change it to `b: fields.char('X-Name')`, then in the DB I now have 2 columns (a and b), with all the data sitting in the outdated column A, while all the new records being stored since in column B.

Both, `-u` and `--update` leave the old data in column A.

What I am looking for is a way of automatically migrating data from column A to column B, and dropping the deprecated A column.
Something like Liquibase for Java.

Comment: Sorry, You are right. As i was in great hurry i haven't tried it properly. Both fields resides in DB.

Comment: Don't forget to use the -d switch as well to say which database you want the module updated in. e.g, -d my_database -u my_module